# Cannot establish connection between server and client using socket.io with NodeJS, ReactJS and Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have read blogs and seen videos where this results in successful connection between the server and client, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work on my system.

This is the code on the server side:

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const PORT = 3001;

io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('a user connected.');
});

http.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('listening on port ' + PORT);
});
```

And this is the code on the client side:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io('http://127.0.0.1:3001');

function Test() {

    return (
        <div>
            Test
        </div>
    )
}

export default Test;
```

- I have checked the versions of both socket.io and socket.io-client and they are at 3.0.4
- I have tried using `io.connect(url)` instead of just `io(url)`
- I have tried replacing *127.0.0.1* with *localhost* and even *192.168.29.101*. (I'm sorry, just a beginner and not sure how these things work in depth).

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to wrap the socket in `useEffect()` and add transports. Something like that:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import openSocket from "socket.io-client";

function App() {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = openSocket("http://localhost:3001", {
        transports: ["websocket"],
    });

    socket.on("message", data => {
      setResponse(data);
    });

  }, []);

  return (
    <p>
      {response}
    </p>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In your server you need to specify the event to emit:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const server = app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log("listening on port 3001");
});

const io = require("socket.io")(server);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("Client connected");
    socket.emit("message", "Hello Socket!");
});
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention this in my original post but I have tried this as well. Doesn't seem to work either. (I did try again using the exact code you've written)

Comment: Maybe you need to check if there's any problem with Cors. Since Socket.IO v3, you need to explicitly enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). You can simply solve it adding transports in your client side code. Edited my answer with a simple server code example and edited the client code.

Comment: This did it. Thank you so much!